# Creating bootable USB: does `dd` overwrite partition table, formatting, filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, dd, usb-drive

I'm creating a bootable USB in order to install NixOS. Given a USB at /dev/sda this could be done by running:

```bsh
# download the ISO
wget https://channels.nixos.org/nixos-21.11/latest-nixos-minimal-x86_64-linux.iso

# erase the disk
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4M

# write the image
sudo dd if=latest-nixos-minimal-x86_64-linux.iso of=/dev/sda bs=4M
```

But before I do this, do I need to format the drive (choose a partitioning scheme, i.e. GPT or MBR, choose a filesystem, i.e. exFAT, FAT32, etc.), or does `dd` overwrite all that info?

Comment: I've done the same thing `dd`ing a ~6gb redhat or centos iso to a usb stick for installation, rather than a dvd.  no need to erase first.  Do this with any bootable iso, using linux, and dd

Comment: take into account the use of `conv=fdatasync` [(see thislink)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150702/what-does-the-conv-fdatasync-do-in-dd-command-in-linux) and `status=progress`. The later may save you from madness if dd takes too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `of=/dev/sda`, `dd` will overwrite **everything** starting from physical block #0, including any partition tables and filesystem metadata.

Erasing the disk before writing the ISO is an unnecessary step, unless you need to give the bootable USB to someone else and/or otherwise need to ensure that any data that used to be on the USB is definitely erased.

Comment: Using dd writes random data into the normal areas of partition tables, whether MBR or gpt. You may have to dd the beginning of the drive to zero out partition table, so blank and then you can repartitions drive. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth mentioning, after you do in linux

```
dd  if=somebootableimage.iso  of=/dev/sdx
```

the usb stick will be problematic  if you wish to reuse that usb stick under Microsoft Windows.  The Windows disk manager will not let you recreate a NTFS partition on it, giving the impression the usb stick is *broken*.

If there is a way in Windows in diskpart in the command prompt window to fix I do not know but...

in linux do the following to make the USB stick microsoft windows compatible again

- let's say the usb stick shows up in linux as `/dev/sdx` simply for syntax reasons, change the `x` to the correct letter for you
- `parted /dev/sdx`
- `mklabel gpt`
- choose yes when prompted it will destroy all data
- `exit` from parted
- unplug usb stick from computer

now the usb stick will have a basic gpt partition table at the start of it, with no partitions defined in it which is ok, and will make the windows disk manager happy.  As opposed to having whatever data that came from some {bootable} iso image that windows doesn't like and won't work with.

consider doing this with any usb stick if it is problematic in Windows and won't format, if it at least shows up as some `/dev/sd?` block device in linux then often you have a good change of recovering the usb stick for microsoft windows use.